# Crashing Application Upon Opening (Unity Android)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Here's the error I'm getting at my Log

> 02-05 11:35:47.393 3257-3257/? E/audit: type=1701 audit(1517801747.380:523): auid=4294967295 uid=10182 gid=10182 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=16078 comm="UnityMain" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" sig=11
>   02-05 11:35:47.661 3689-4463/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{ce3ccded0 u0 com.steet383.rh.google/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
>   02-05 11:35:47.672 3689-3960/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{f2ed271d0 u0 com.steet383.rh.google/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t802}: app died, no saved state
>   02-05 11:35:47.682 3689-15446/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{6ed08d5d0 u0 SurfaceView - com.steet383.rh.google/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
>   02-05 11:35:47.683 3689-15446/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.steet383.rh.google/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2849 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:1079 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1783 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2889 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2839 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:2203 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:701  
>   02-05 11:35:47.705 3689-3960/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.steet383.rh.google/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2849 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:1079 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1783 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2889 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2839 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2654 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.removeAllWindows:596 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.removeAppFromTaskLocked:358

Does anyone have an idea about this. I tried also disabling the dynamic batching on my build setting but no luck. It's still there.

Comment: Need to provide more info.

Comment: that's only the info I've got because it's only the thing on my Log sir.

Comment: Put you manifest an activity file as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just unchecked the dynamic and static batching . I don't know why it affects my application . But thanks anyway guys.